# OpenJPA one to one NO COMPARTE LA primary key

Tags: jpa, openjpa

Tenemos las siguientes dos tablas vinculadas con una relación uno a uno con clave primaria compartida:

```
CREATE TABLE "PERSONAL"."INASISTENCIAS" (
        "**ID_INASISTENCIA**" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "FECHA_COMIENZO" DATE NOT NULL,
        "FECHA_FIN" DATE NOT NULL,
        "CANTIDAD_DIAS_SOLICITADOS" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    )


CREATE TABLE "PERSONAL"."INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO" (
        "ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO" INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "FECHA_PRUEBA" DATE NOT NULL,
        "INSTITUCION_PRUEBA" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        "MATERIA" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    )


ALTER TABLE "PERSONAL"."**INASISTENCIAS**" ADD CONSTRAINT "INASISTS_PK" **PRIMARY KEY   ("ID_INASISTENCIA")**;

ALTER TABLE "PERSONAL"."**INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO**" ADD CONSTRAINT "INASISTSESTUD_PK" **PRIMARY KEY ("ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO")**;

ALTER TABLE "PERSONAL"."INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO" ADD CONSTRAINT "INASISTSESTUD_INASISTS_FK" **FOREIGN KEY
("ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO")
REFERENCES "PERSONAL"."INASISTENCIAS"
("ID_INASISTENCIA")**;
```

Las entidades **JPA** correspondientes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="INASISTENCIAS", schema="PERSONAL")
public class **Inasistencia** implements Serializable {

    private int **idInasistencia**;
    private Date fechaComienzo;
    private Date fechaFin;
    private int cantidadDiasSolicitados;

    public Inasistencia() {
    }

    **@Id**
    **@SequenceGenerator**(name="INASISTENCIAS_IDINASISTENCIA_GENERATOR",
    sequenceName="PERSONAL.SEQ_INASISTENCIAS")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
    generator="INASISTENCIAS_IDINASISTENCIA_GENERATOR")
    @Column(name="ID_INASISTENCIA")

    public int getIdInasistencia() {
        return this.**idInasistencia**;
    }   

    public void setIdInasistencia(int idInasistencia) {
        this.idInasistencia = idInasistencia;
    }

    //uni-directional one-to-one association to InasistenciasEstudio
    @**OneToOne**(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, 
    CascadeType.REFRESH}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="ID_INASISTENCIA", 
    referencedColumnName="ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO", nullable=true,  
    updatable=false, insertable=false)

    public InasistenciaEstudio getInasistenciasEstudio() {
        return this.**inasistenciasEstudio**;
    }

    public void setInasistenciasEstudio(InasistenciaEstudio 
       inasistenciasEstudio) {
        this.inasistenciasEstudio= inasistenciasEstudio;
    }
....
}


@Entity
@Table(name="INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO", schema="PERSONAL")
public class **InasistenciaEstudio** implements Serializable {

    private int **idInasistenciaEstudio**;
    private Date fechaPrueba;
    private String institucionPrueba;
    private String materia;

    public InasistenciaEstudio() {
    }

    @**Id**
    @Column(name="ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO", unique=true, nullable=false)    
    public int getIdInasistenciaEstudio() {
        return this.**idInasistenciaEstudio**;
    }

    public void setIdInasistenciaEstudio(int idInasistenciaEstudio) {
        this.idInasistenciaEstudio = idInasistenciaEstudio;
    }   
....
}
```

Inasistencias e InasistenciasEstudio comparten la clave primaria cuyovalor es generado automaticamente por el motor OPenJPA (SNAPSHOT_2.1.2) al momento del comit usando la secuencia definida en la entidad Inasistencia (SEQ_INASISTENCIAS).

**El problema** es que el valor de la clave en insistencia.idInasistencia no es propagado a inasistencia.inasistenciaEstudio.idInasistenciaEstudio cuando ambbas entidades relacionadas son persistidas. Según entendemos de la documentación JPA esto debiera ocurrir automáticamente sin anotaciones adicionales.

Código de prueba:

```
Inasistencia inasis = new Inasistencia();
*<set Inasistencia att..>*

InasistenciaEstudio inasisEstudio = new InasistenciaEstudio();
*<set InasistenciaEstudio att..>*

inasis.setInasistenciasEstudio(inasisEstudio);

entityManager.saveObject(inasis);
```

trace log de la prueba:

> 2132  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  executing prepstmnt -928506975 
>       SELECT t0.USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, t0.FECHA_PRUEBA, 
>               t0.INSTITUCION_PRUEBA, t0.materia, t0.MOMENTO_BAJA, 
>               t0.TIPO_PRUEBA 
>           FROM PERSONAL.INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO t0 
>           WHERE t0.ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO = ? optimize for 1 row 
>       [params=(int) 0]
>       2178  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  [46 ms] spent
>       2199  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  executing prepstmnt 1867579702 
>       **VALUES NEXTVAL FOR PERSONAL.SEQ_INASISTENCIAS**
>
> 2201  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  [2 ms] spent
>       2221  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  executing prepstmnt 430574027 
>       INSERT INTO PERSONAL.**INASISTENCIAS** (ID_INASISTENCIA, 
>               USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, CANTIDAD_DIAS_SOLICITADOS, 
>               FECHA_COMIENZO, FECHA_FIN, ID_ROL_PERSONAL, 
>               ID_TIPO_INASISTENCIA, LIBRE_REFERENCIA, MOMENTO_BAJA, 
>               ID_REGIMEN_TRABAJO) 
>           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
>       [params=(int) **90**, (String) TestEntidades, (int) 10, (Date) 2016-07-28, (Date) 2016-08-07, (int) 271465, (int) 1, (Date) 2016-07-28, (null) null, (int) 1]
>       2356  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  [134 ms] spent
>       2357  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  executing prepstmnt 1692880180 
>       INSERT INTO PERSONAL.**INASISTENCIAS_ESTUDIO** (ID_INASISTENCIA_ESTUDIO, 
>               USUARIO_ULTIMA_MODIFICACION, FECHA_PRUEBA, INSTITUCION_PRUEBA, 
>               materia, MOMENTO_BAJA, TIPO_PRUEBA) 
>           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
>       [params=(int) **0**, (String) TestEntidades, (Date) 2016-08-07, (String) Udelar, (String) Matematica, (null) null, (String) Parcial]
>       2374  LicenciasDomain  TRACE  [main] openjpa.jdbc.SQL -  [17 ms] spent

Comment: hi there, welcome to StackOverflow in Spanish, could you please translate your question or move it to StackOverflow.com thank you and have an amazing day!

Comment: Ok, I've already do it.